# Custom authentication with Azure AD and Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating the authentication for an app that requires Office 365 integration. I got the authentication in the front-end to work but I'm not sure what is the best way to link this authentication information to Firebase Cloud Functions.
I saw answers related to this that say I should redirect the user to the login page of Azure AD and get the token back to my cloud functions to mint a custom token and give that one back to the user.
But this is not clear for me, how can I confirm this token the user sent is valid?
And can I use the `admin.auth().verifyToken()` to get the user information from this custom token?